# Git Pre-push hooks not aborting push in case of more than one checks

Tags: git, shell, githooks, yarnpkg

in git hooks -
I wanted to check for jshint errors and yarn integrity check before pushing, so I added below in pre-push.
so it's something like this -

```
    # Pre-push hooks
    # Lint stuff before committing
    grunt jshint eslint tslint
    # Verifies that versions and hashed value of the package contents 
      in the project’s package.json matches that of yarn’s lock file.
    yarn check --integrity
```

- Here if jshint gives error but if yarn integrity check passes, still
  it allows push. It will abort iff yarn fails.
- If I reverse the order then if yarn check fails and if jshint passed, 
  then also it pushes. It will abort iff jshint fails.

So it fails push only if the last check fails while in other cases it states the error but still pushes it

Comment: Shameless plug but you can check out my helper [`git-riff`](https://github.com/hauleth/git-riff) which allows you to write separate script for each task in hook and handle such case for you.

Answer (score 8):

This is really a question about writing scripts.

In sh/bash scripts, a series of commands just runs the series of commands:

```
cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
```

It does not matter if any one command "fails" (returns a nonzero exit status); the script goes on to run the next one.

The final exit status of the script is the exit status of the *last command that ran*, unless you provide a particular status:

```
exit 0
```

(zero means success).

If you wish to exit immediately upon any command failure, you can set the `-e` option:

```
set -e
cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
```

This is rather crude and not always the right thing to do.  Note that if `cmd2` fails (exits nonzero), `cmd3` is not even started, but the shell does exit with the failing exit status of `cmd2`.

To be particularly fancy, you can *save* the exit status of each command:

```
cmd1; cmd1_status=$?
cmd2; cmd2_status=$?
cmd3; cmd3_status=$?
```

The `$?` variable expands to the exit status of the command that just ran.

Of course, now you have to figure out what to do with the three status-es, since you can only exit with *one* of them, but you can now exit with whichever one failed first, if any:

```
test $cmd1_status != 0 && exit $cmd1_status
test $cmd2_status != 0 && exit $cmd2_status
exit $cmd3_status
```

Now your script runs all three commands unconditionally, but returns the status of the first nonzero failure.  If cmd1 and cmd2 both returned a zero status, the script exits with whatever the status from cmd3 was.

Comment: For 2 cmnds, 
test cmd1_status != 0 && exit $cmd1_status
test cmd2_status != 0 && exit $cmd2_status
It still pushes even if last command fails

Comment: I had two typos above that I will fix.  Meanwhile, if that's not it, show the exact code (cut and paste into original question, perhaps; remember to use the "format as code" stackoverflow markup).

Answer (score 0):

Self advertisement here: If you want to be very fancy, you can use helper functions that I wrote a while ago (for a commit hook).

You run it like this:

```
set -e

run_check 'flake8' . flake8
run_check 'ESLint' . ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js frontend/js
exit_test
```

And get output like this:

```
flake8 OK
ESLint OK
```

Or if you are less lucky:

```
./frontend/tests.py:8:83: E999 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
flake8 FAILED

/home/frax/Programowanie/organizer/organizer2/frontend/js/utils.js
  11:18  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token ;

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

ESLint FAILED
Some check(s) failed.
```

The exit code of `exit_test` is the exit code of the last failed check. When using `set -e` it becomes exit code of the whole script.

Code:

```
# Use run_check to run groups of independent tests, that should all be run even
# if some of them fail (but you still want to know about failure).

# testing_exit_code variable stores last non-zero exit code of the check, or 0,
# if no check failed so far.

# Important note: using trap prevents set -e from intercepting check failures,
# so it's safe (and recommended) to use -e in testing script.

# Example:

#
#    run_check 'Foo check' . echo Foo
#    run_check 'Bar check' . echo Bar
#    exit_test  # fail if any test failed
#

testing_exit_code=0

function run_check () {
    # Usage: run_check <check name> <working directory> <command> [args...]
    local cmd="$1"
    trap 'testing_exit_code=$?; echo "$cmd FAILED"; return 0' ERR
    local cmd_wd="$2"
    shift 2
    ( cd "$cmd_wd" && "$@" )  # run the command
    echo "$cmd OK"
}

function exit_test () {
    if (( testing_exit_code != 0 )); then
        echo "Some check(s) failed."
    fi
    exit $testing_exit_code
}
```

The output looks nicer if you add some coloring. I actually have them in my original script, but omitted them for brevity and portability sake. I can share the version with colors separately, if you are interested.